# Converting a Bidimensional Array (Numbers) Into A Dimensional Array and Viceversa on Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm in need of help right now. I need to convert 2 dimensional array of numbers to a one dimensional array in Java. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] data = new String[][] {
            { "Foo", "Bar" },
            { "A", "B" }
        };

        String[] flattened = flatten(data);

        for (String x : flattened) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    public static <T> T[] flatten(T[][] source) {
        int size = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < source.length; i++) {
            size += source[i].length;
        }

        // Use the first subarray to create the new big one
        T[] ret = Arrays.copyOf(source[0], size);
        int index = source[0].length;
        for (int i=1; i < source.length; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(source[i], 0, ret, index, source[i].length);
            index += source[i].length;
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

If you want it for primitive types, you'll have to write an overload for each primitive type, but you can use `new int[size]` instead of `Arrays.copyOf` at that point.

Comment: Instead of overloading the method for every primitive, it's easier to write a couple of "boxing" methods which manually boxes the primitives to objects - and still use the flatten method for the flattening :)

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean? I can't see how that would really help me turn an int[][] into an int[]. It would also be much less efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

A Java 8 solution could look something like this:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ArrayConverter {

public static String[] flatten(String[][] array) {
    // Create a stream of the given array
    return Stream.of(array)
            // Map each of its elements to a stream (thus creating a
            // one-dim-array inside the stream, so to say)
            .flatMap(Stream::of)
            // Retrieve the stream as array, explicitly calling String to
            // keep the type
            .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
}

}
```

I consciously left out generic types in this example since it makes the Array Initialization somewhat confusing. Let me know if you need it tho.

Notably; if you want to use this conversion for Arrays of primitive types you should use the corresponding flat Methods of the Stream Class.
E.g. if you're using int-Arrays use:

```
Stream.flatMapToInt(...)
```

to retrieve an `IntStream` with actual primitive int-Values thus dodging autoboxing into `Integer` Objects.

[JavaDoc of Stream for reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)