# What is the best way to combine several arrays into one single array

Tags: java, arrays

Hey, I was trying to combine several arrays of type double into one single array, what is the best way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Most maintainable or most efficient?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663632/converting-a-bidimensional-array-numbers-into-a-dimensional-array-and-viceversa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create an array of the right size (by going through and summing the lengths of all the source arrays)
- Repeatedly call `System.arraycopy` to copy one source array at a time into the target array, updating the place where you copy it to on each iteration.

So something like:

```
public static double[] Combine(double[][] arrays)
{
    int totalLength = 0;
    for (double[] source : arrays)
    {
        totalLength += source.length;
    }
    double[] ret = new double[totalLength];
    int index = 0;
    for (double[] source : arrays)
    {
        System.arraycopy(source, 0, ret, index, source.length);
        index += source.length;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't an overflow only occur if there's about 16 GB of data?

Comment: Never underestimate the constraints on your inputs: http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: Do you mean overflow of the totalLength?

Comment: Well, I was just kidding, but yes, you'd need 16 GB of doubles to overflow. However, I'm sure that there are applications that do. I think one of the improvements for JDK 7 is arrays with a `long` length.

Comment: This feature was dropped. Would check it anyway -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method from the Guava library, which is open-source and will have an actual binary release probably later this month:
[Doubles.concat(double[]...)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#concat(double[]...))